# Xcode swift - unresolved identifier error

Tags: ios, swift

Please help me to edit my code. I cant seem to fix this error.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let avPlayerViewControler = AVPlayerViewController()
    var avPlayer:AVPlayer?
    var videoNumber:Int!
    var url:String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let urlpathString:String? = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("url", ofType: "mp4")

        if let urlPath = urlpathString {

            switch videoNumber {
            case 1 : url="20"
            case 2 : url="10"
            default : break
            }
            let movieUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlPath)

        }
        self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: movieUrl)
        self.avPlayerViewControler.player = self.avPlayer

    }

    @IBAction func Cool(sender: UIButton) {
        videoNumber=1
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, which identifier?

Comment: Self.avPlayer =AVPlayer(URL: urlPath)

Comment: `movieUrl` is out of scope...

Comment: What does that mean? How could i fix that? Thanks

Comment: You *have to* learn what "scope" is. :)

Comment: How is the result of the `switch` ever used even after the scope issue is fixed?

Comment: Please note the second related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37709764/swift-video-does-not-play-when-button-is-clicked where OP asks for a bit help about the logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to move the two lines regarding the `avPlayer` and `avPlayerViewControler` inside the `if` since the constant `movieUrl` is only available inside that scope - it only *exists* inside the scope it was defined in, it does not exist outside of the `if`-block!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let urlpathString:String? = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("url", ofType: "mp4")

    if let urlPath = urlpathString {

        switch videoNumber {
            case 1 : url="20"
            case 2 : url="10"
            default : break
        }
        let movieUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlPath)
        self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: movieUrl)
        self.avPlayerViewControler.player = self.avPlayer
    }
}
```

Comment: I have done what you said. When I click the button it does not play the video. Please help

Comment: @MorganEvansMedia unfortunately that is an entirely different issue. You should rethink your code logic, which method does what and gets called at what time. Currently on a button press you only set *some* number, how should that number change *anything*?

Comment: @MorganEvansMedia ... and you should think about accepting my answer since it apparently fixed your issue, namely the error. Your code still does not run but that is exactly what your second question is for. If you feel like my answer is correct you can click the checkmark on its left.